# Updating a column in SQL Server with difference in value of some column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I have two tables in SQL Server like this:

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I need to update the `Pending qty` column in table 1 by subtracting the `Invoice qty` column's value from it.

After updating my table 1 should look like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is that really all the data involved? i.e.: If we provide an `update` statement that achieves what you ask what happens if you run it twice? Would it be acceptable for Pending Qty to be -5, -6 and -7?

Comment: Please don't post data as images, provide it as tabular formatted `text`, or DDL and DML statement. What have you tried so far? It seems you know you need a `JOIN` and an `UPDATE`, so please include the SQL you tried and explain why it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Please show what parts you can do & explain how you are stuck. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Don't ask us to do your (home)work.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to join both tables using `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.PendingQty =  t1.t1.PendingQty - t2.Invoice.Qty
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.PONumber = t2.PONumber
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.[Pending qty] -= ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t2.[Invoice qty])
                                    FROM Table2 AS t2
                                    WHERE t1.[PO Number] = t2.[PO Number]
                                    AND t1.[Part number] = t2.[Part number]), 0);
FROM Table1 AS t1;
```

I was guessing that there might be multiple invoice rows for each pending table row.

Comment: But as mentioned, you also need to think about how you're cleaning up that invoiced table. Note that I added the sub-select to avoid issues that could happen if you just did an INNER JOIN and there were multiple rows for each.

Comment: Thanks.Will Try this